# Как использовать сертификаты X.509?

Tags: c#, веб-сервер, https, шифрование, сертификат

Допустим я хочу написать 2 консольные программы: клиент и сервер. Создам самоподписанные сертификаты, установлю их на машинах клиента(тут в доверенные .cer) и сервера(тут с приватным ключем .pfx). Использую c#.

1. Как связать мой сервер-консоль с сертификатом?
   Похоже что в веб серверах(IIS к примеру) есть возможность установить сертификат, то есть это привязка серверного приложения к конкретному сертификату. Как без веб сервера связать сертификат с программой? Нужно ли в коде приложения как-то учитывать то что это будет https?
2. Как проверять сертификат на клиент-консоле? Слышал что в браузерах эта логика прописана. Вытащить программно сертификаты из хранилища и прописать логику сравнения с тем который приходит с сервера самому или связать программы с сертификатами можно через cmd и OS сама все проверит?

Comment: Ответ очень сильно зависит от того, на каком языке вы собираетесь писать сервер и клиента. Но в любом случае вам нужно будет использовать какую-либо библиотеку поверх сокета, через который будут взаимодействовать клиент и сервер. Способ подключения сертификата зависит от конкретной библиотеки.

Comment: Использую C#, но хотелось бы понимать общую схему, а там уже разберусь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно появился пост который отвечает на эти вопросы
https://habr.com/ru/post/581740/

Answer (score 1):

Протокол TLS в .NET реализован классом `System.Net.Security.SslStream`. Этот класс реализует и клиентскую сторону, и серверную.

[Подробнейший пример есть в MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

В этом примере серверный сертификат используется в вызове метода [`SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasserver?view=netframework-4.8):

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
```

В примере путь к файлу сертификата передается как параметр командной строки. Сертификаты в .NET представляются классами  [`System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate?view=netcore-3.1) (используется в примере) и [`System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netcore-3.1) (рекомендуется Майкрософтом).

В примере из MSDN сертификат конструируется статическим методом [`X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromcertfile?view=netcore-3.1).

Клиент устанавливает защищенное соединение с сервером вызовом метода [`SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=netcore-3.1). Этот метод проверяет сертификат сервера и согласовывает параметры защищенного соединения.

Проверка серверного сертификата состоит из двух этапов. Сначала внутренние классы .NET парсят сертификат(ы), присланные сервером и проверяют на базовые ошибки - корректный синтаксис, время NotValidBefore/NotValidAfter, Purpose, целостность цепочки сертификатов, соответствие имени сервера имени в сертификате (имя сервера передаётся как аргумент в `AuthenticateAsClient`). Затем вызывается делегат типа [`RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback?view=netframework-4.8), который передаётся как аргумент конструктора клиентского потока `SslStream`. В примере клиента, ссылку на который я привел в начале, используется тривиальный коллбэк. Он останавливает аутентификацию, если при проверке серверного сертификата обнаружены какие-либо ошибки.

Защищенное соединение по протоколу TLS устанавливается после того, как на серверной стороне отработает метод `AuthenticateAsServer`, а на клиентской стороне `AuthenticateAsClient`.

Класс `SslStream` предоставляет интерфейс типа `Stream`. Для отправки данных используется метод `SslStream.Write`, а для получения - `SslStream.Read`. Всё шифрование/расшифрование и, при необходимости, переустановка соединения, происходят прозрачным образом внутри `SslStream`.